# RxJS5 => subscriber's onCompleted callback not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs5

I have these two methods on a queue. I have implemented some form of backpressure, whereby the observables created from the methods will only fire events if the user fires a callback, all via observables. The problem is that I cannot get the onCompleted handler to fire in the main subscriber to `drain()`. What surprises me is that onNext will fire for the same subscriber, so why won't onCompleted fire? I would think that between the takeUntil call and the heavy handed $obs.complete() that the onCompleted handler in the subscriber would fire...

```
Queue.prototype.isEmpty = function (obs) {

    if (!obs) {
        // this is just a dummy observable
        // I wish Rx had Rx.Observable.dummy() alongside
        // Rx.Observable.empty(), but oh well
        obs = Rx.Observable.of('dummy');
    }

    return this.init()
        .flatMap(() => {
            return obs; // when you call obs.next(), it should fire this chain again
        })
        .flatMap(() => {
            return acquireLock(this)
                .flatMap(obj => {
                    return acquireLockRetry(this, obj)
                })
        })
        .flatMap(obj => {
            return findFirstLine(this)
                .flatMap(l => {
                    return releaseLock(this, obj.id)
                        .map(() => {
                            console.log(' => LLLL1 => ', l);
                            return l;
                        });
                });
        })
        .filter(l => {
            // filter out any lines => only fire event if there is no line

            return !l;
        })
        .map(() => {
            //  the queue is now empty
            obs.complete(); // <<<<<<<<<< note this call
            return {isEmpty: true}
        });


};


Queue.prototype.drain = function (obs, opts) {

    opts = opts || {};

    const isConnect = opts.isConnect || false;
    const delay = opts.delay || 500;

    let $obs = obs.takeUntil(this.isEmpty(obs))
        .flatMap(() => {
            return this.init();
        })
        .flatMap(() => {
            return acquireLock(this)
                .flatMap(obj => {
                    return acquireLockRetry(this, obj)
                });
        })
        .flatMap(obj => {
            return removeOneLine(this)
                .flatMap(l => {
                    return releaseLock(this, obj.id)
                        .map(() => l);
                });
        });


    process.nextTick(function(){
        obs.next('foo foo foo');
        $obs.next('bar bar bar');
        $obs.complete();
    });


    return $obs;

};
```

What is driving absolute bonkers, is that I cannot get the onCompleted callback to fire, when I call the above like so:

```
const q = new Queue();

const obs = new Rx.Subject();

q.drain(obs).subscribe(

    function (v) {

        console.log('end result => ', colors.yellow(util.inspect(v)));

        setTimeout(function () {
            // the following call serves as the callback which will fire the observables in the methods again
            obs.next();
        }, 100);

    },
    function (e) {
        console.log('on error => ', e);
    },
    function (c) {
        // this never gets called and it is driving me f*cking crazy
        console.log(colors.red(' DRAIN on completed => '), c);
    }

);

obs.subscribe(
    function (v) {
        console.log('next item that was drained => ', v);
    },
    function (e) {
        console.log('on error => ', e);
    },
    function (c) {
        // this gets called!
        console.log(colors.red(' => obs on completed => '), c);
    }
);
```

When I call the above, I just get this:

```
next item that was drained =>  foo foo foo
next item that was drained =>  bar bar bar
 => obs on completed =>  undefined
```

The reason I just get those 3 lines, is because I do this:

```
process.nextTick(function(){
    obs.next('foo foo foo');
    $obs.next('bar bar bar');
    $obs.complete();
});
```

but *why* wouldn't explicitly calling `$obs.complete();` fire this callback:

```
 function (c) {
            // this never gets called and it is driving me f*cking crazy
            console.log(colors.red(' DRAIN on completed => '), c);
        }
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think I figured this out, what a crazy library this RxJS

Most likely to do things right, you should probably be using take() or takeUntil() or similar

So I did this:

```
Queue.prototype.drain = function (obs, opts) {

    if (!(obs instanceof Rx.Observable)) {
        opts = obs || {};
        obs = new Rx.Subject();
    }
    else {
        opts = opts || {};
    }


    const isConnect = opts.isConnect || false;
    const delay = opts.delay || 500;

    process.nextTick(function () {
        obs.next();
    });


    let $obs = obs
        .flatMap(() => {
            return this.init();
        })
        .flatMap(() => {
            return acquireLock(this)
                .flatMap(obj => {
                    return acquireLockRetry(this, obj)
                });
        })
        .flatMap(obj => {
            return removeOneLine(this)
                .flatMap(l => {
                    return releaseLock(this, obj.id)
                        .map(() => ({data: l, cb: obs.next.bind(obs)}));
                });
        })
        //  here is the key part!
        .takeUntil(this.isEmpty(obs));


    return $obs;

};
```

that seems to have done the trick. I was pretty hopeless for awhile. If you want further explanation of how this works, please inquire within.